# Difference between Stochastic Gradient Descent and Sklearn's Stochastic Average Gradient (SAG) solver?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, stochastic-gradient-descent

How does stochastic gradient descent varies from Sklearn's SAG (Stochastic average gradient) solver?

**Edit**: Many sklearn models like Ridge, LogisticRegression, etc accept SAG as a solver